# pause audio clip in java

Tags: java, audio

I have a code with 2 classes MPlayer and Audio.

MPlayer has the GUI (JButtons, JPanel and JFrame etc), and Audio has the code to play audio.
The problem is when i call the pause method in class MPlayer, it does not pause the audio.

Can someone help me with it?

**MPlayer.java:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MPlayer extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    ImageIcon icon1, icon2, icon3, icon4;
    JPanel pan1;
    JFrame frame;
    JMenuBar bar;
    JMenu menu;
    JMenuItem menuItem;
    JButton btn1, btn2;

    public void initGUI() {
        bar = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("Open");
        bar.add(menu);
        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
        menu.add(menuItem);
        BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
        FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();

        pan1 = new JPanel();
        frame = new JFrame("Music Player");
        frame.setLayout(bl);
        pan1.setLayout(fl);
        frame.setJMenuBar(bar);

        icon1 = new ImageIcon("./play.jpg");
        icon2 = new ImageIcon("./pause.png");
        icon3 = new ImageIcon("./stop.jpg");
        icon4 = new ImageIcon("./wallpaper.jpg");

        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btn1 = new JButton(icon1);
        btn1.setVisible(true);
        btn2 = new JButton(icon3);
        btn2.setVisible(true);
        pan1.add(btn1);
        pan1.add(btn2);

        frame.add(new JLabel(icon4), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(pan1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setFocusable(true);

        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        menuItem.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Audio aud = new Audio();

        if (e.getSource() instanceof JMenuItem) {
            if (((JMenuItem) (e.getSource())) == menuItem) {
                aud.openFile();
            }
        }

        if (btn1.getIcon() == icon1) {
            btn1.setIcon(icon2);
            aud.pause();
        } else if (btn1.getIcon() == icon2) {
            btn1.setIcon(icon1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MPlayer gui = new MPlayer();
        gui.initGUI();
    }
}
```

**Audio.java:**

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Audio {
    File file;
    AudioInputStream audio;
    AudioFormat fmt;
    DataLine.Info dli;
    Clip c;
    JFileChooser jfc;

    public void openFile() {
        try {
            jfc = new JFileChooser();
            jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
            file = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            fmt = audio.getFormat();
            dli = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, fmt);
            c = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(dli);
            c = AudioSystem.getClip();
            c.open(audio);
            c.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public void pause() {

        if (c.isRunning()) {
            c.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for now i am just playing short length .wav files.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP requested.

Comment: I'd had never done this if they'd had let me edit it properly. But unfortunately, i am not able to edit it

Comment: @Masu I've locked the question. Don't edit out the content of the question because you want it removed. That's not how this site works. If you have questions about this, then [ask a question on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything in the same thread. Swing applications start on what is called the Event Dispatch Thread - this is the thread that handles all UI interactions. You should not be performing long-running tasks (like playing audio) in this thread.

Spawn a new thread to play the audio, and I think you'll find things work better. You can do this manually or you can use something like a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to do this, which would allow you to provide regular feedback on the "progress" of your playing (i.e. you can say you're X% done with the file etc, or that there are 3m25s left etc).

The class documentation for SwingWorker is quite good and I highly suggest you read it, regardless of whether or not you are going to use it, as it has some very good suggestions for threads in Swing in general.